# Java forcing interface on 3rd party class through anonymous class

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, extends, implements

I've got some 3rd party beans that have method signatures that fit quite well onto an existing interface but it does not implement the interface.

Now I would like to do something like this, which doesn't work. Is there some workaround?

```
 someBean.setSomeInterface(
         new Interface() extends SomeBeanThatMatchesAlotOfMethodsOfTheInterface {
     });
```

Comment: How about the Adapter pattern? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern for this

Define a class that implements your interface and in all the method calls delegate to the `someBean` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I think about all you could do is extend their class (like you did above) and then say implements.

Eg.

```
public class MyImplementingClass extends SomeBeanThatMatchesAlotOfMethodsOfTheInterface implements MyInterface {

....
}
```

Of course by basing their code on your interface it is possible that it could break in the future. Just be aware of that.